# Thread stopped responding on JBoss 5

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have a number of threads spawn in a JBoss 5.1 server (Java 6u22) that process large numbers of input files in parallel.

Suddenly, one of the threads stopped responding. Other threads are fine. I cannot get a thread dump from that server any more. Could anyone provide some ideas as to what may have caused this?

Here is all I have in the log:

```
WARN    (Thread-9) [arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper_18] - TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 7f000001:bb15:4fd24ef6:6f42 in state  RUN
WARN    (Thread-10) [arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction_58] - Abort of action id 7f000001:bb15:4fd24ef6:6f42 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
WARN    (Thread-10) [arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.CheckedAction_2] - CheckedAction::check - atomic action 7f000001:bb15:4fd24ef6:6f42 aborting with 1 threads active!
WARN    (Thread-9) [arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper_18] - TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 7f000001:bb15:4fd24ef6:6f42 in state  CANCEL
WARN    (Thread-9) [arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper_18] - TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 7f000001:bb15:4fd24ef6:6f42 in state  CANCEL_INTERRUPTED
WARN    (Thread-9) [arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper_6] - TransactionReaper::check worker Thread[Thread-10,5,jboss] not responding to interrupt when cancelling TX 7f000001:bb15:4fd24ef6:6f42 -- worker marked as zombie and TX scheduled for mark-as-rollback
WARN    (Thread-9) [arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper_11] - TransactionReaper::check failed to mark TX 7f000001:bb15:4fd24ef6:6f42  as rollback only
WARN    (Thread-10) [arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper_13] - TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Thread-10,5,jboss] missed interrupt when cancelling TX 7f000001:bb15:4fd24ef6:6f42 -- exiting as zombie (zombie count decremented to 0)
```